# Hovering over child element firing mouse out

Tags: jquery, hover

On `hoverIn` - I want to append a box, slide it up.

On `hoverOut` - box should slide down and then remove the box

On a simple list it works perfectly, I can hover over the sliding element.
But if I'm using an image, it causes a flicker effect when I try hover over the sliding element.

- [Working](http://jsfiddle.net/XCgvd/).
- [Not working](http://jsfiddle.net/tXJDQ/2/).

Hover over the elements then try mouse the cursor on the red box that appears.
What's the difference here, am I missing something?

Also for related objects and similar cases, do I need to use `stopPropagation`? Can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

See the most recent version of your [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXJDQ/28/). I updated the jQuery to select the elements slightly differently, so now it should function the way you want it to.

```
$('#aaa li').hover(function(){
    $(this).append('<div id="box"></div>'); 
    $(this).children('div').stop().animate({
        bottom:'0px'
    },{
    queue:false,duration:350
    });       
}, function() {  
    $(this).children('div').stop().animate({
        bottom:'-53px'
    },{
        queue:false,duration:300,complete:function() {
            $(this).children('div').remove(); 
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `img` and the `div` are not a parent/child relationship.  An `img` can't contain anything.  You will need to give them a common parent.  Perhaps a span, or just use the `li` like you are in your first example.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tXJDQ/26/ as an example of such.

Comment: i dont follow, the append places the <div id="box/> in the right place [after the image] and im calling it using .next(); ?

Comment: Your question is titled "hovering over child element firing mouse out".  You are not hovering over a child element, you are hovering over a sibling.  The hover is on the `img`, mousing into the `div` IS mousing out.

Answer (score 0):

When you are hovering over the simple li (working example) and the box slides up under your mouse pointer ---> you are still technically hovering over the li.

However, when you are hovering over the img (not working example) and the box slides up under your mouse pointer ---> you are being passively 'hovered out' of the image.

In the second case jquery sees that you have hovered out (even if it's passively), and begins the hover out sequence.

You have two options (That I can think of) to resolve this:

1. put the image as background to the li.
2. Create a div that'll contain both the image and the box. then you must set hoverin/hoverout effects on that parent div.